# Error opening a Realm with Realm.10.6.0: No RealmObjects. Has linker stripped them?

Tags: c#, realm

I have Windows forms app in C# that was working perfectly fine with older Realm library 3.4.0.
Now, I updated to Realm 10.6.0 through NuGet console and all packages and libraries were installed fine, no errors during compiling. I'm using .Net 4.7.2. I have FodyWeaver.xml in the project included.
But, i get error when i try to open and read RealmConfiguration from a realm file.

```
config = new RealmConfiguration(dbPath);                 
realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```

I can open the realm in MongoRealmDBStudio without problems.
However, from the code, i get an error on second line:
"No RealmObjects. Has linker stripped them?"
Config object has values null for ObjectClasses and Schema.

Even if i try to create the default configuration and load classes manually, i get similar error "No properties in RealmContact, has linker stripped it?"

From the documentation and other similar questions it looks like it's related with linker somehow. But I don't work with Realm often and I don't know where to look at.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to wipe your bin and obj folders? Sometimes, VS will cache certain things during a NuGet update and we'll see peculiar behavior like what you describe. If that doesn't work, feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet.

Comment: Yes, i did. Didn't help. Ok, I'll open an issue. Thanks.